# React native Execution failed for task ':expo:compileDebugKotlin'

Tags: android, react-native

I have a react native app (cloned from another repo) which uses expo modules/packages, and after installing all the remaining expo packages manually using `yarn add expo-<...>`, I'm really stuck at this one (the title).

Some details about the project:

`package.json`:-

```
...
"expo": "^44.0.0",
"react": "17.0.1",
"react-dom": "17.0.1",
"react-native": "0.64.3",
...
```

`gradle version`:- gradle-7.3.3-bin.zip

`java -version`:-

```
java version "17.0.1" 2021-10-19 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.1+12-LTS-39)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.1+12-LTS-39, mixed mode, sharing)
```

The error:- `npx react-native run-android`:-

```
> Task :expo:compileDebugKotlin FAILED
w: Detected multiple Kotlin daemon sessions at build/kotlin/sessions

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

Execution optimizations have been disabled for 1 invalid unit(s) of work during this build to ensure correctness.
Please consult deprecation warnings for more details.
883 actionable tasks: 864 executed, 19 up-to-date
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: /home/user/project/node_modules/expo-gl/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/gl/GLContext.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /home/user/project/node_modules/expo-gl/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/gl/GLContext.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: /home/user/project/node_modules/expo-notifications/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/notifications/notifications/presentation/builders/ExpoNotificationBuilder.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: /home/user/project/node_modules/expo-video-thumbnails/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/videothumbnails/VideoThumbnailsModule.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /home/user/project/node_modules/expo-video-thumbnails/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/videothumbnails/VideoThumbnailsModule.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: /home/user/project/node_modules/lottie-react-native/src/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/lottie/LottieAnimationViewManager.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /home/user/project/node_modules/lottie-react-native/src/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/lottie/LottieAnimationViewManager.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: /home/user/project/node_modules/react-native-android-keyboard-adjust/android/src/main/java/net/zubricky/AndroidKeyboardAdjust/AndroidKeyboardAdjustModule.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /home/user/project/node_modules/@react-native-async-storage/async-storage/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativecommunity/asyncstorage/AsyncStorageModule.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /home/user/project/node_modules/@react-native-async-storage/async-storage/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativecommunity/asyncstorage/AsyncStoragePackage.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: [2] Wrote GeneratedAppGlideModule with: [com.bumptech.glide.integration.okhttp3.OkHttpLibraryGlideModule, com.dylanvann.fastimage.FastImageOkHttpProgressGlideModule]
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
e: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.pom.java.LanguageLevel
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.core.CoreLanguageLevelProjectExtension.<init>(CoreLanguageLevelProjectExtension.java:26)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.core.JavaCoreProjectEnvironment.<init>(JavaCoreProjectEnvironment.java:42)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreProjectEnvironment.<init>(KotlinCoreProjectEnvironment.kt:26)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$ProjectEnvironment.<init>(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:118)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$Companion.createForProduction(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:420)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.createCoreEnvironment(K2JVMCompiler.kt:226)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:152)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:52)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:88)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:44)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:98)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:371)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:105)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:249)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.access$compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:38)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner$compile$2.invoke(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:80)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:92)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:602)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.access$execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:93)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1644)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor26.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:360)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:587)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:828)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:705)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:704)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':expo:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Internal compiler error. See log for more details

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 31s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: /home/user/project/node_modules/expo-gl/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/gl/GLContext.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /home/user/project/node_modules/expo-gl/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/gl/GLContext.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: /home/user/project/vugs-app/node_modules/expo-notifications/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/notifications/notifications/presentation/builders/ExpoNotificationBuilder.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: /home/user/project/node_modules/expo-video-thumbnails/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/videothumbnails/VideoThumbnailsModule.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /home/user/project/node_modules/expo-video-thumbnails/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/videothumbnails/VideoThumbnailsModule.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: /home/user/project/node_modules/lottie-react-native/src/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/lottie/LottieAnimationViewManager.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /home/user/project/node_modules/lottie-react-native/src/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/lottie/LottieAnimationViewManager.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: /home/user/project/node_modules/react-native-android-keyboard-adjust/android/src/main/java/net/zubricky/AndroidKeyboardAdjust/AndroidKeyboardAdjustModule.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /home/user/project/node_modules/@react-native-async-storage/async-storage/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativecommunity/asyncstorage/AsyncStorageModule.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /home/user/project/node_modules/@react-native-async-storage/async-storage/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativecommunity/asyncstorage/AsyncStoragePackage.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: [2] Wrote GeneratedAppGlideModule with: [com.bumptech.glide.integration.okhttp3.OkHttpLibraryGlideModule, com.dylanvann.fastimage.FastImageOkHttpProgressGlideModule]
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
e: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.pom.java.LanguageLevel
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.core.CoreLanguageLevelProjectExtension.<init>(CoreLanguageLevelProjectExtension.java:26)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.core.JavaCoreProjectEnvironment.<init>(JavaCoreProjectEnvironment.java:42)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreProjectEnvironment.<init>(KotlinCoreProjectEnvironment.kt:26)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$ProjectEnvironment.<init>(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:118)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$Companion.createForProduction(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:420)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.createCoreEnvironment(K2JVMCompiler.kt:226)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:152)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:52)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:88)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:44)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:98)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:371)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:105)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:249)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.access$compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:38)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner$compile$2.invoke(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:80)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:92)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:602)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.access$execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:93)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1644)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor26.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:360)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:587)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:828)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:705)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:704)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':expo:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Internal compiler error. See log for more details

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 31s

    at makeError (/home/user/project/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
    at /home/user/project/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (/home/user/project/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:94:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (/home/user/project/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:186:9)
```

Before this error, there were errors related to expo modules only for example:

```
> Task :expo-camera:compileDebugKotlin FAILED
> Task :expo-av:compileDebugKotlin FAILED
> Task :expo-file-system:compileDebugKotlin FAILED
...
```

So, I managed to get rid of them by installing the specified package using `yarn add <...>`, and they went away, but this `> Task :expo:compileDebugKotlin FAILED` I cannot solve because there isn't a package named `expo` alone, and I have already installed `expo-cli`, so I am now hopeless.

Can someone provide some insights on how to solve this problem?

**EDIT 1**:-

I tried this link, but didn't solve, sharing here if someone could understand the problem:- https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/15989